# A phrase to describe a state that I'm still better than anyone else and should be grateful

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

In my language, we often say an imperative phrase that literally translates to "look *down*". It means we must see / remember that there are always people *below us* who are not as lucky as us, thus we should be grateful.

How do we say that in English? Is there a short phrase for that? I often hear in movies that they use the phrase "you should be grateful", but I need the other phrase that emphasizes I'm more lucky than anyone else below me.

Comment: "Think yourself lucky [you're not in X's situation]."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe **"[Count your blessings](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/to-count-your-blessings)"**, which implies "Even though you don't think your situation is great, you should be thankful that it isn't worse."